# After Effect\ Issue in aerender command line tool

Tags: render, after-effects

**[ERROR] NVAPI error (C:\code\rtsdk\adobe-ae\cc13.1\src\Util\DriverInfo.cpp:78):
[LOG 4] CPU fallback enabled**

Getting this error while executing following command (on After effect enabled enviornment)
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2015.3\Support Files>aerender -pro
ject D:\proj\01.aep

- Please revert asap

Answer (score 0):

Disable Ray-traced 3D in target comps

I mean, it was rendering 40 seconds per frame, got 4 hours for a minute.

After spending quite some time, turns out it was this that was triggering the "CPU fallback enabled"

And, for some reason, it only affected comps that had cameras in.